# Error when creating a queueTrigger Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

When adding a queueTrigger in my project i get this error

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'AutoAssigned'.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Storage account connection
> string 'Storage' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App
> Setting. [2021-08-05T16:42:02.274Z] Error indexing method 'AutoAssigned'

This is my queue code

```
public static class AutoAssigned
{
    [FunctionName("AutoAssigned")]
    public static void Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

That just happens when I execute my project in Visual Studio, not even when I'm calling the queue, in this example my connection is empty but i do have the connection in my local.settings.json

Comment: `Connection = ""` this value needs to be the name of your app setting property containing your connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Connection` property to specify the app setting that contains the storage account connection string to use.

```
[FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items", Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] string myQueueItem, 
    ILogger log)
{
    ....
}
```

Also, you can set the `StorageAccount` attribute that takes the name of an app setting that contains a storage connection string.

```
[StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
```

For reference see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations)